# InvalidFilter with Azure Resource Manager resources API

Tags: azure, odata, azure-resource-manager

Trying to use the Azure Resource Manager API to search for resources.  First I tried this:

```
GET /subscriptions/xxx/resources?$filter=startswith(name,%20'web')&api-version=2015-01-01
```

> Invalid $filter `'startswith(name, 'web')'` specified in the query string. Details: 'Unsupported filter function found:'startswith'. Property name:'name'. Supported functions: 'substringof''

Then I tried this:

```
GET /subscriptions/xxx/resources?$filter=substringof('web',%20name)%20eq%20true&api-version=2015-01-01
```

> Invalid $filter `'substringof('web', name) eq true'` specified in the query string. Details: 'Unsupported token found in $filter string.'

I'm not an OData expert, so I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong, or if I'm trying to do something that's not really supported in this API.

Comment: Checked OData v2 and v3 specs, the syntax looks okay from there.. OData v4 is a bit different, the function is called substring there. Could you try leaving out *eq true*, since it is kind of pointless as substringof is supposed to return a boolean anyway?

Comment: @juunas Yeah it was the *eq true*, I figured it out by doing a trace of the `Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains` PowerShell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query must be:

```
GET /subscriptions/xxx/resources?$filter=substringof('web',%20name)&api-version=2015-01-01
```

Leave out eq true. Even though it can be seen as part of official examples of v2 and v3 odata protocol, it seems the Azure API doesn't support this.